# Using Jquery UI Autocomplete in IE is not triggering source [Invalid calling object jquery.ui.js (735,2)]

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI autocomplete. In all other browsers works fine, except in IE. It gives me an *Invalid Calling Object error* at jquery.ui.js (735,2).

This is the JQuery code that is throwing the error...

```
_delay: function( handler, delay ) {
    function handlerProxy() {
        return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
            .apply( instance, arguments );
    }
    var instance = this;
    *return setTimeout( handlerProxy, delay || 0 );*
},
```

I honestly have no clue of what is happening, since it works on other browsers.

```
var input = $('input', ph);
input.autocomplete({
  create: function () {
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      return $("<li></li>").append(myself._createLabelTag(item.label)).appendTo(ul);
    };
  },

  source : function(request, response) {
    var term = request.term.toUpperCase();
    var matches = $.map(this.valuesArray, function(tag) {
      if (myself._createLabelTag(tag.label).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(term) >= 0) { 
        return tag;
      }
    });
    response(matches);
  }.bind(this),

  select : function(event, ui) {
    $('#' + this.htmlObject + '-input').val(ui.item.value);
    myself.dashboard.processChange(this.name);
  }.bind(this)
});
```

Because of the Invalid Calling Object error, The source event is not being called, and therefore the autocomplete options are not being rendered.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I googled a lot, but nothing relevant showed up ...

Comment: Is page somewhere online? What IE version is the problem? What jQuery version do you use?

Comment: What page? Do you mean JQuery UI documentation page?
Yes, I already read everything there.

Comment: No, question is how to reproduce the code and examine it inside IE.

Comment: Please provide more details about this issue. Please indicate what specific Versions of Internet Explorer you see this issue. Please describe what version of jQuery UI you are using. Please describe what steps we can take to replicate the issue.